# Filter by NO-TAG option

Tags: feature-request, filtering, tag-search

It would be nice to have an option to search not only for *TAG* but also for option *DON'T HAVE SUCH TAG*.

For example I want to look for a tag **angular** but without **angular-ui-bootstrap**, so my request could be:

```
[angular]![angular-ui-bootstrap]
```

Answer (score 10):

it looks like it's already there

```
 [angular]-[angular-ui-bootstrap]
```

[image]